# Text with special class as excerpt (or exclude special class)

Tags: excerpt, content, exclude

I am new in Wordpress and I am trying to customize my own theme.

All my posts are starting with a kind of content that I don't want to become the excerpt.
It is kind of header.

Is there a way to use as excerpt only content with class `.myOnwnExcerpt`, or maybe it will be easier to ask wordpress to run excerpt rule excluding text with class `.notToBeDisplayedAsExcerpt`. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Easiest is to set manual excerpts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest course of action would be to write manual excerpts instead of having the system generate them.

Second, would be to wrap your "content that isn't an excerpt" in a shortcode. If you look at the [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) function, which generates excerpts from post content, one of the first thing it does is [strip shortcodes](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2611). For example, if you had a shortcode like this:

```
function foocode($atts,$content){
  return $content;
}
add_shortcode('foo','foocode');
```

Anything in the post body such as `[foo]Hello[/foo]` would not appear in the generated excerpts. Note that the "exceprt" is not necessarily the chunk of text that displays on the index page. If the the theme uses `the_content()` the post content will break on the `<!-- more -->` tag, or nothing at all, and your content will still appear.